# how to repeat header rows for each group within the same page in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to repeat header row (column names) for each group of my report which are in the same page.
Please note that i know how to repeat headers on each page, but this is specifically related to repeating header rows on the same page but for each group as shown in the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below the steps which worked for me.

Step 1. Right click on the group 'Country'-->Insert Row --> Inside Group Above

Step 2.Right click on the group 'Country' which will now be a merged cell of 2 cells 
--> Split cells-->Cut the above cell which says 'Country' and paste to the cell below.

Step 3.Now you can see a blank row below your headers, cut and paste the headers to this blank row. It will repeat above each 'Country' group.

Comment: Thanks NiveaGM, the solution was simple and easy to implement.you really saved my day, thanks a ton

Comment: Hi @Deepak, I am glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I have stolen this from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38339fd0-df84-455c-b13f-2de25f1b1008/repeat-row-and-column-headers-for-each-group?forum=sqlreportingservices

1. Drag the original table into a list.
2. Right-click the list handle, select Tablix Properties.
3. In Tablix Properties pane, in the DatasetName drop-down list, select the main dataset of your original table.
4. Right click the Details group, and click Group Properties.
5. In Group Properties dialog, click add to define a group for the details row.